# Parse xml to different members based on Attribute value

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, converters, xstream

I am working on XML to java parsing. I have a scenario similar to this.

I need to parse XML into java based on the attribute value.

I need to parse all **EMPLOYEE** elements with attribute `PERMANENT="Y"` in one member and with attribute `PERMANENT="N"` in another member.

```
<EMPLOYEE PERMANENT="Y">
    <DETAILS NAME="AA"  ID="1"  AGE="28" />
    <DETAILS NAME="BB"  ID="2"  AGE="29" />
</EMPLOYEE>
<EMPLOYEE PERMANENT="N">
   <DETAILS NAME="CC"  ID="3"  AGE="28" />
    <DETAILS NAME="DD"  ID="4"  AGE="29" />
</EMPLOYEE>
```

Java

```
public class Employee
{

   // @XStreamAlias("EMPLOYEE") and attribute PERMANENT="Y"
    private Details permanentEmployee;

   // @XStreamAlias("EMPLOYEE") and attribute PERMANENT="N"
    private Details tempEmployee;

}
```

I am not sure how to do this.

Can some one help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the using the [java xml api](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/)

The XPath expression to select the "DETAILS" nodes will look something like this:

```
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
//...

XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "/documentBody/EMPLOYEE[@PERMANENT="Y"]/DETAILS"
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

This returns a nodeList that you need to then iterate through for each DETAILS node, which I would assume describes one employee.

Comment: Thank you. Can you help how to do this using xstreamAlias

Comment: @Patan XStream is a xml serialization library for Java. I highly doubt you are able to do it using the XStreamAlias annotation, this annotation is meant to define a class or field xml alias... You ask to parse all Employee elements... well, if they were serialized using the XStream library you should just be able to use the .fromXML() method. If they were not serialized using XStream I don't really see a point in you using this library, its primary purpose is xml serialization. Java already provides an excellent API for XPath query.